# Graying out Silverlight web part

Tags: silverlight

I've created a Silverlight webpart. It's shown on a SharePoint page on which there are also some links which trigger SharePoint popups, actually the Silverlight web part triggers one itself.

Now when the popup is displayed, the rest of SharePoint is grayed out; except for the Silverlight control! It stays active, and worse; when you click it, it comes up in front of the SharePoint popup effectively making it impossible to close that popup.

Is there a way to get around this? I assume it's a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a custom SL web part? Set the [isWindowless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979728%28VS.95%29.aspx) parameter to true on the SL control. Note that this might degrade performance.